# https vs http issue with rails route in facebook applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, url, routes

I have a facebook application developed on ruby on rails and deployed on passenger + apache server.

Now when i go to the facebook page where the app is added and click on that application, it loads in the browser as secure browsing is enabled for me.
In case i disable the facebook secure browsing, it's redirecting to a different url and gives error.

I would like to know what would be the solution to handle users having secure browsing disabled and also what changes to be done in the application as

(just sample urls)

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage/359678449?sk=app_25735749
```

and

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage/359678449?sk=app_25735749
```

hits different rail routes.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code added to apache.conf file fixed the issue,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://apps.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```